# Using SageMaker inference services to deploy Recbole

Tags: amazon-sagemaker, inference

Is there any resource the explains deploying Recbole model on AWS SageMaker for inference? I have the model trained on S3 and want to use SageMaker inference services to create a serverless endpoint. I have created the endpoint but facing issues on how to provide input to the invoke_endpoint function of SageMaker to get the predictions. Any help would be appreciated. Thanks

Comment: Could you share more details about what issue you are facing?